# Dynamically change CSS style of cell in <h:dataTable> column

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

how to calculate cell values of B column and how to change their css style dynamically
[image: how to calculate the values of column B and how to change his color]

my java object :

```
public class MyObject{
   private Date date;
   private int A;
   private int C;

   //Getters & Setters
}
```

my managed bean :

```
public class MyBean(){
    List<MyObject> List = myObjectDao.FindAll();

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

my jsf code :

```
<p:dataTable id="idList" var="list" value="#{myBean.list}" >
    <p:column headerText="DATE">
        <h:outputText value="#{list.date}"  />
    </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="A">
        <h:outputText value="#{list.A}"  />
    </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="B">
        <h:outputText value="????????" style="???????"  //>
    </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="C">
        <h:outputText value="#{list.C} />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just use the conditional operator `?:` in EL.

E.g.

```html
<c:set var="B" value="#{(list.A / list.C) * 100}" />
<h:outputText value="#{B}" style="display: block; background-color: #{B lt 50 ? 'red' : (B lt 90 ? 'blue' : 'green')}" />
```

If `B` is also used elsewhere in the model or controller, then you could add a `public int getB()` method which just contains `return (A/C) * 100;` and then use `#{list.B}` instead of `#{B}`.

Note that proper design is to use a CSS class instead. E.g.

```html
<h:outputText value="#{B}" styleClass="percentage #{B lt 50 ? 'poor' : (B lt 90 ? 'average' : 'good')}" />
```

with

```css
td .percentage {
    display: block;
}

.percentage.poor {
    background-color: red;
}

.percentage.average {
    background-color: blue;
}

.percentage.good {
    background-color: green;
}
```

You can of course also perform the determination of CSS style/class in a getter method as suggested by the other answer, but that's a poor separation of concerns.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but the result of <c:set var="B" value="#{(list.A / list.C) * 100}" scope="request" />  is always =0 ????

Comment: Sorry, remove `scope="request"`.

Comment: but i have this warning "Could not make numeric conversion for less than operation", caused by #{B lt 50 ? 'red' : (**B lt 90** ? 'blue' : 'green')}"

Comment: EL syntax validation in the average IDE is poor. I have turned it off in Eclipse. If it was invalid, it would surely have thrown an exception during runtime.

Comment: one last question :( how to change the color of the cell
not the color of <h:outputText ?

Comment: That's not possible this way. It's exactly the reason why I've set the output text to `display: block` so that it spans the entire cell. If you have another content which you'd also like to put in same cell with the same background color, then better replace `<h:outputText>` by `<div>` on which the style class is set and put everything therein (and now you can remove `display:block` style because the `<div>` is that already by default).

Comment: I found how to do it. I just change the style of <p:column  style="....."> instead <h:outputText style="...."> it works very well ... thank you friend !!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing the logic within your `MyObject` class

So I would call it in `JSF` like this:

```
<p:column headerText="B">
    <h:outputText value="#{list.calculateB()}" styleClass="list.createLabel()">
</p:column>
```

Inside `MyObject`

```
public double calculateB() {
   return (A/C)*100;
}


public String createLabel() {
   if(calculateB() > 90) {
       return "GREEN";
   //DO YOUR LOGIC

}
```

in `CSS`

```
.GREEN {
background-color: #00FF00 !important;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code has resolved my issue.

```
style="#{event.eventStatusDesc eq 'Completed' ? 'color: #32cd32;font-weight: bold;':(event.eventStatusDesc eq 'Rescheduled till Further Notice' ? 'color: blue;font-weight: bold;' : 'color: black;')}" />
```