# Prime Faces Exporting dynamic cell value

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, el

I have this table in Tomcat 7 jsf 2.1

My purpos is to customize the text presented in the cell. it's an Integer and I show the 
string from the toString of an object taken from a list

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,4,8,2
```

I transform it with

```
1,f(2)->"TWO",g(3)->"XXX",4,5
1,f(2)->"TWO",g(4)->"yyyy",4,5
```

This is the table

```
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" 
                 lazy="true"
                 value="#{cfgCentraleController.lazyModel}" 
                 paginator="true" rows="10"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 var="centrale" 
                 selection="#{cfgCentraleController.selectedCentrali}"
                 emptyMessage="Nessun dato per la ricerca"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50">

        <f:facet name="header">
            Lista Centrali
        </f:facet>  

        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px" />  

        <p:column  sortBy="#{centrale.idDevices}" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="idDevices" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:commandLink value="#{centrale.idDevices}" update=":centraleDetailForm:display" oncomplete="centraleDialogJS.show()"  title="View">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{centrale}" target="#{cfgCentraleController.selectedCentrale}" />    
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column sortBy="#{centrale.ridonda}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Ridonda" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{centrale.ridonda}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column sortBy="#{centrale.idMarca}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Marca" />
            </f:facet>
             <c:set var="MM" value="#{cfgCentraleController.resolveRete(centrale.idRete)}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{MM}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column sortBy="#{centrale.idRete}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Rete" />
            </f:facet>
           <c:set var="RR" value="#{cfgCentraleController.resolveRete(centrale.idRete)}" />
           <h:outputText value="#{RR}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column sortBy="#{centrale.descrizione}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Descrizione" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{centrale.descrizione}" /> 
        </p:column> 

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Note" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{centrale.note}" /> 
        </p:column> 

        <f:facet name="footer" >
            <p:row>  
                <p:column>
                    <h:commandLink>  
                        <p:graphicImage library="img" width="20" name="XLS.png" value="XLS.png" />  
                        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="dataTable" fileName="cars" />  
                    </h:commandLink>  

                    <h:commandLink>  
                        <p:graphicImage library="img" width="20" name="PDF.png" value="PDF.png" />  
                        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="dataTable" fileName="cars"/>  
                    </h:commandLink>  

                    <h:commandLink>  
                        <p:graphicImage library="img" width="20" name="CSV.png" value="CSV.png"/>  
                        <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="dataTable" fileName="cars" />  
                    </h:commandLink>  
                </p:column>


                <p:column  colspan="1" style="text-align: left" >
                    <p:commandLink id="pdf" ajax="false">  
                        <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/pdf.png"/>  
                        <pe:exporter type="pdf" target="dynamicColumnsTable" fileName="dynamicColumnsTable"/>  
                    </p:commandLink>  
                    <p:spacer height="20"/>  
                    <p:commandLink id="xls" ajax="false">  
                        <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/excel.png"/>  
                        <pe:exporter type="xlsx" target="dynamicColumnsTable" fileName="dynamicColumnsTable"/>  
                    </p:commandLink> 
                    <p:commandButton value="Nuova Centrale" oncomplete="newCentraleDialogJS.show()" icon="ui-icon-star" title="Crea una nuova centrale"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Elimina Centrale" onclick="confirmationJS.show();"  update="dataTable" icon="ui-icon-trash"/>
                </p:column>    
            </p:row>  
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
```

The bean is

```
package com.telenia.tsam.beans.config.centrali;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

/**
 *
 * @author Riccardo
 */
@ManagedBean
public class Centrale implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 481317100879125703L;

    private int idDevices;
    private String note;
    private String descrizione;
    private int idMarca;
    private int idRete;
    private int ridonda;

    /**
     * @return the idDevices
     */
    public int getIdDevices() {
        return idDevices;
    }

    /**
     * @param idDevices the idDevices to set
     */
    public void setIdDevices( int idDevices ) {
        this.idDevices = idDevices;
    }

    /**
     * @return the note
     */
    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    /**
     * @param note the note to set
     */
    public void setNote( String note ) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    /**
     * @return the descrizione
     */
    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }

    /**
     * @param descrizione the descrizione to set
     */
    public void setDescrizione( String descrizione ) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    /**
     * @return the idMarca
     */
    public int getIdMarca() {
        return idMarca;
    }

    /**
     * @param idMarca the idMarca to set
     */
    public void setIdMarca( int idMarca ) {
        this.idMarca = idMarca;
    }

    /**
     * @return the idRete
     */
    public int getIdRete() {
        return idRete;
    }

    /**
     * @param idRete the idRete to set
     */
    public void setIdRete( int idRete ) {
        this.idRete = idRete;
    }

    /**
     * @return the ridonda
     */
    public int getRidonda() {
        return ridonda;
    }

    /**
     * @param ridonda the ridonda to set
     */
    public void setRidonda( int ridonda ) {
        this.ridonda = ridonda;
    }


}
```

This is the resolver in cfgCentraleController

```
 public Marca resolveMarca( int idMarca ) {
        if (this.marche != null) {
            for (Marca marca : marche) {
                if (marca.getIdMarca() == idMarca) {
                    return marca;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    public Rete resolveRete( int idRete ) {
        if (this.reti != null) {
            for (Rete rete : reti) {
                if (rete.getIdRete() == idRete) {
                    return rete;
                }

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I use the indication of BalusC [Dynamically change CSS style of cell in <h:dataTable> column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014770/dynamically-change-cell-values-and-css-style-of-h-datatable) and data are shown correctly

But export complains about this issue

```
giu 25, 2013 5:16:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [/stdPortal/stdPages/config/centrale/List.xhtml @148,51 value="#{MM}": /stdPortal/stdPages/config/centrale/List.xhtml @147,102 value="#{cfgCentraleController.resolveRete(centrale.idRete)}": Property 'resolveRete' not found on type com.telenia.tsam.beans.config.centrali.cfgCentraleController] with root cause
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'resolveRete' not found on type com.telenia.tsam.beans.config.centrali.cfgCentraleController
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:237)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:214)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:325)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getType(BeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:215)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:84)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:172)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getType(AstIdentifier.java:50)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:172)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.Exporter.exportValue(Exporter.java:131)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter.addColumnValue(ExcelExporter.java:204)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter.exportCells(ExcelExporter.java:164)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter.exportRow(ExcelExporter.java:147)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter.exportAll(ExcelExporter.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter.export(ExcelExporter.java:61)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:99)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:818)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.telenia.tsam.Filters.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I think that It use a different aproach to resolve EL. Or i'm doing something wrong?