# Dynamic color on every row in h:datatable

Tags: jsf, xhtml, mojarra

## Context

I'm working on a very old system which is literally falling apart and my actual task is to fix it.

This old system uses old libraries which I can't really modify cause maybe it would fix a small part of the system but it would just make the rest of it much more broken. Though, I can probably add new libraries which won't interfere with the old ones.

## My Problem

What I'd like to do is to add a class on certain rows of the table based on a server-side condition like `rowStyleClass="#{searchTask.hasLinkedDecision(task) ? 'info' : ''}"` but I can't find any solution since apparently there is several libraries named JSF but none of them is the same and the one my system depends on seems to be the only one that doesn't support dynamic rows style classes.

## JSF Dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

## Problematic Code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
.....
<h:dataTable id="dttask"
             binding="#{searchTask.taskTable.dataTable}"
             value="#{searchTask.taskTable.dataList}" var="task"
             styleClass="table table-striped table-hover">
         <!--rowStyleClass="#{searchTask.hasLinkedDecision(task) ? 'info' : ''}"-->

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                .....
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <a href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/faces/pages/tasks/editing/add-tasks.xhtml?id=#{task.noTask}">
            <h:outputText value="#{task.noTask}"/>
        </a>
    </h:column>

    <h:column sortBy="">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText value="No CT"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>

        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty searchTask.getNoCT(task)}">
            <div class="tooltipobjet" tabindex="0"
                 style="border-bottom: 1px dotted black;">
                .....
            </div>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:commandLink actionListener="#{searchTask.sortDataListTask}">
                    .....
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <abbr title="#{searchTask.getTaskLabel(task.principal)}">
            .....
        </abbr>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:commandLink actionListener="#{searchTask.sortDataListTask}">
                    .....
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{searchTask.getLabelValueDomainSearch('domain.type.task', task.type)}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:commandLink actionListener="#{searchTask.sortDataListTask}">
                    .....
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <div class="tooltipobject" tabindex="0"
             style="border-bottom: 1px dotted black;">
            .....
        </div>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:commandLink actionListener="#{searchTask.sortDataListTask}">
                    .....
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{task.dateConform}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{constants.DATE_TIME_FORMAT_CREATE_JOUR_HH_MM}"/>
        </h:outputText>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:commandLink
                        actionListener="#{searchTask.sortDataListTask}">
                    .....
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{searchTask.getAdminUnitAbbr(task.treatingAdminUnit)}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:commandLink actionListener="#{searchTask.sortDataListTask}">
                    .....
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{searchTask.getLabelValueDomainStatusByUser(task.status, task.statusEditDate)}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
.....
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9 Things... the one but last is your answer

1. This question does not seem related to 'stabelizing' an application that almost breaks down but an improvement.
2. JSF (Mojarra in your case) 2.2.4 is not **that old**.
3. Does not look like you are using `jsp` but facelets
4. You cannot reproduce in plain java-se sdk with class with a `main` method and no additional libraries and so the java tag on the question is not correct.
5. There are not several libraries called JSF, there is an api called JSF which is implemented by two implementations. Mojarra and MyFaces, both implementing the same api.
6. Where did you see `rowStyleClass` on the `h:datatable` https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/dataTable.html
7. If you get deprecation warnings compile time it most often means you do use some newer versions of libraries (less old ones) but **you** still use old methods from previous versions.
8. Answer is in [Changing h:datatable cell color or style dynamically in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038769/changing-hdatatable-cell-color-or-style-dynamically-in-jsf) or with a little more code [conditionally set class values for h:datatable cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630735/conditionally-set-class-values-for-hdatatable-cells)
9. This **is** the answer for your version of libraries. If you do not want to use this and don't want to 'duplicate' code IN columns (not ON colums) you could create a small composite component

Comment: Thanks for your help but i don't understand the 4th point and I'd like to know if there is any alternative so I don't have to copy paste the styleClass condition on every column? 

BTW I wasn't necessary talking about JSF/Mojarra when I said *old libraries* but when you compile and most of the console output are warning about usage of deprecated methods.....

Comment: Thank you very much! Your help is really appreciated! The point 9 is exactly what I wanted to know and I was complaining more about libraries which are so old that they do not even exists anymore. Though, I shouldn't complain about anything in here anyway. And sorry if I'm hard to understand or if my english is not perfect. I'm a french canadian so... Thanks again